# Arranging rectangles in a circle with equal distance

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, 2d, trigonometry

I'm writing a program that renders mind maps. So far, I've succeeded in drawing the root node and the first level of child nodes around it, in a circle.

This is the code that renders the mind map nodes:

```
const root = data.find((node) => node.parent === undefined);
const level1 = data.filter((node) => node.parent === root.id);
root.x = 0;
root.y = 0;
root.level = 0;

await addMindMapNode(scene, root);
const radius = 2;
const slice = (2 * Math.PI) / level1.length;
for (let i = 0; i < level1.length; i++) {
    const level1node = level1[i];
    level1node.level = 1;
    const angle = slice * i;
    const x = root.x + radius * Math.cos(angle);
    const y = root.y + radius * Math.sin(angle);
    level1node.x = x;
    level1node.y = y;
    await addMindMapNode(scene, level1node);
}
```

You can find the [whole program on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/drawing-a-mind-map-with-threejs-and-react-part-v-qi17x?file=/src/renderMindMap.js).

The output looks like this (with different number of child nodes, from 1 child to 9 children):

[image: rendered nodes]

As you can see, depending on the number of child nodes, the distribution of the child nodes around the root node in the center looks more or less uneven and not pleasing to the eye, especially with 3, 7 or 9 child nodes.

This is because of the rectangular format of the child node boxes. The center points of the boxes have the exact same distance between them, but the length of the distance (shown as red line segments below) is different, depending on position:

[image: coordinates and angles with 7 child nodes]

I have to find a way to make it so that the red circle sections are equal in size.

So my question is:

**How can I calculate the angle at which to render each purple box so that the distance between each box looks to be the same (i.e. take into account the width and height of each box)?**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's my attempt (with diagrams too!) :

So I noticed that the problem was that the calculated angles being used to generate the co-ordinates of the rectangles needed to shift a little by some small angle `β`. Something like:

[image: beta]

Somebody more math-savvy than I am can probably do better, but for my attempt I noticed that I could tinker with the angle generated by the rectangle itself, given its dimensions. Like:

[image: beta_prime]

So, plugging that in:

```
  const angle = slice * i;
  // == addition starts here
  const opp_hyp = 60/120;
  const b_prime_degrees = Math.atan(opp_hyp);
  const b_prime = 180 * b_prime_degrees/Math.PI;   // converting to radians
  const x = root.x + (radius * Math.cos(angle-b_prime));
  const y = root.y + (radius * Math.sin(angle-b_prime));
  // == addition ends here
```

Using that, I got the following outcomes for 3, 7 and 9:
[image: outcome_1]

I wasn't too satisfied, so totally on a whim, I decided to try the *other* angle in that triangle i.e. `180-β`

```
  const angle = slice * i;
  // == addition starts here
  const opp_hyp = 60/120;
  const b_prime_degrees = Math.atan(opp_hyp);
  const new_guy = 180 * (180-b_prime_degrees)/Math.PI;
  const x = root.x + (radius * Math.cos(angle-new_guy));
  const y = root.y + (radius * Math.sin(angle-new_guy));
  // == addition ends here
```

Using ***that***, I got the following outcomes for 3, 7 and 9:
[image: outcome_2]

...which *kinda* looks better, sort of.

Hopefully somebody more knowledgeable than I am comes along and helps you with a definitive answer. Till then, I hope my attempts at least help nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer and the effort with the diagrams! I'm afraid it's not acceptable yet, since the rectangles aren't evenly distributed, but this is probably a good starting point.

Comment: Alright. Twas worth a shot. I might maybe take another crack at it. If so, will update answer. Either way, all the best